# Working with matrices problem with MatrixForm

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra

I'm just trying to set up a Matrix 24 by 24 with indices that start from 0 to 23

```
Array[t, {24, 24}, {0, 0}];
Do[t[k, j] = k + j, {k, 0, 23}, {j, 0, 23}];
t[1, 1] // MatrixForm
MatrixForm[t]
```

Everything seems fine but when I'd like to have the output in matrixForm the result is simply t
( https://gyazo.com/312ac29c839ca63b831a3e22423f5571 )

Does anybody knows why?

Comment: `Clear[t]` `t = Array[#1 + #2 &, {24, 24}, {0, 0}];` `Dimensions@t` and finally `t // MatrixForm`

Comment: in `Array` the `t` is the entries. You might want to do `ClearAll[t];
T0 = Array[t, {24, 24}, {0, 0}];
Do[t[k, j] = k + j, {k, 0, 23}, {j, 0, 23}]; MatrixForm[T0];`

Comment: Also check `Table`. It is the most natural way, in Mathematica, to create the matrix you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Do[t = Array[s, {24, 24}, {0, 0}]; s[k, j] = k + j, {k, 0, 23}, {j, 0, 23}]
MatrixForm@t
```

[image]